# xmlHttpRequest and manipulating a table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I currently use a java-script function to load content based on a selection, here is an example of the function

```
function loadActions2(id,value,title) {
        var url = title+"?value="+value;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp=new ActiceXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        divtarget.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This will load a php file, with desired content.
My main site looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td> Text 1234</td>
      <td>
       <label onclick"loadActions2('id','value','title')"> Click here</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the loaded php file contains another table. 
Now, im looking for a solution, to add the content of the file directly to the table, so this would mean, my php file would look like this

```
<tr>
   <td>Text 999</td>
</tr>
```

And should be added directly to the existing table, not in a seperate div/table.

Is this possible?

Comment: You have typo on the 'else':
xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign id to the table, and when request is successful, append HTML to the table:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("mytable").innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by user Gothdo, assign an ID to the table tag.

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
<td> Text 1234 </td>
</tr>

<td> <label onclick="loadActions2('id','value','title');"> Click here </label> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

then, when the request(s) arrive, you just append the response getting the ID from the table:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    var content = xmlhttp.responseText;
    var node = document.createElement("tr");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(content);
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(node); 
  }
}
```